# Getting calculated fields with sequelize models

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add calculated fields to my model, that I want to reuse without rewriting custom queries all the time.

I've tried two different ways of adding calculated fields as Sequelize.literal's that allow me to get the desired result from 2 out of three use cases.

The model is a classic ordering system.

1. There are articles, articles has a stock count
2. There are orders
3. orders have order rows
4. order rows have an fk to an article, and an ordered amount.

I want a field on the article model that is similar to:

`article.stockQuantity - SUM(orderrows.orderedQuantity) where order.state <> 'fullfilled'`

So when I look at an article I can see how many of those articles are available in stock.

With the sequelize.literal solution I can get close. The result is calculated using a subquery, which is fine for me. An example of a virtual field that does the trick is below.

```js
const article = sequelize.define('article', {
    ...
  stockQuantity: {
type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
  },
availableQuantity: {
    type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.DECIMAL,
      [Sequelize.literal(`(COALESCE((select article."stockQuantity" - sum("orderRows"."orderedQuantity") from "orderRows" left join orders on orders.id = "orderRows"."orderId" where "orderRows"."articleId" = article.id and orders."state" <> 'fullfilled'), 0)) as "availableQuantity"`), "availableQuantity"]),

    },
...
});
```

This works for listing articles with `findAll` and for `get`ing the full article.

However when I try to get an order, in which I have an article listing, the subqueries break.
Because they cannot follow the renaming for the nested children in the subquery.

The resulting sql describes the problem clearly

```sql
--- clipped from the select part of the generated query
    "orderRows->article"."name" AS "orderRows.article.name",
    (
        COALESCE(
            (
                select
                    article."stockQuantity" - sum("orderRows"."orderedQuantity")
                from
                    "orderRows"
                    left join orders on orders.id = "orderRows"."orderId"
                where
                    "orderRows"."articleId" = article.id
                    and orders."state" <> 'fullfilled'
            ),
            0
        )
    ) as "availableQuantity",

---
```

Of course this gives me an error, as the article table is no longer called article when included from a `order.findAll`:

```js
{
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "message": "missing FROM-clause entry for table \"article\"",
}
```

Without having to do excess round-trips to get the calculated fields as a separate query.
Is there a way for me to get get the desired values in the sequelize model system so I have the models as contained business units?